# upload images with php through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ajaxform

carica.html

```html
<td>
    <input type="file" size="30" onchange="preview()" id="upload_immagine">
</td>
<td>
    <div id="divImmagine" > </div>
</td>
```

filejavascript.js

```js
function preview() 
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            document.getElementById("divImmagine").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    image=request.getParameter("upload_immagine");
    document.getElementById("divImmagine").innerHTML=image;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","stampaAnteprima.php", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("image="+image);
}
```

stampaAnteprima.php

```html
<?php
    $file_temp=($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    echo"$file_temp";
?>
```

The line of javascript `image=request.getParameter("upload_immagine");` returns nothing. How do I get the value to pass to php and then read the file via `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` in practice it would be image? Do you have any advice?

Comment: standard ajax doesn't allow for file uploads.

Comment: use malsups file upload plugin for jquery Link : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Another good solution is:  http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: @MarcB You'll have to be more clear as to what "standard ajax" is.  As it stands, every browser other than IE9 and older allows file uploads via XHR.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to send files to php.

You can add more eventlisteners to display the upload progress and error handling.

```
function UploadPhoto(){
    var file = document.getElementById('upload_immagine').files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", file);
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", function(event) { uploadcomplete(event); }, false);
    req.open("POST", "stampaAnteprima.php");
    req.send(formdata);
}
function uploadcomplete(event){
// Your php reply = event.target.responseText 
}
```